# Make a Part of Text Bold inside TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I know that we can use `<Run>` in XAML to achieve what I am asking :

```
<TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run Text="This is" />
    <Run FontWeight="Bold" Text="Bold Text." />
</TextBlock.Inlines>
```

Also I can do it in code behind as follows:

```
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("This is"));
TextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run("Bold Text.")));
```

But my problem is something different:

Suppose I have following Text in my database:

```
This is <b>Bold Text</b>.
```

Now, my Textblock is bound to a field that contains the above text in database.

I want the `text between <b> and </b> to be bold`. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to display HTML, use a Webbrowser control.

```
<WebBrowser Name="myWebBrowser"/>
```

And in your code, pass your text like this:

```
myWebBrowser.NavigateToString(myHTMLString);
```

If not, and bold is the only thing to be done and cannot be nested, you can do it like this:

```
string s = "<b>This</b> is <b>bold</b> text <b>bold</b> again."; // Sample text
var parts = s.Split(new []{"<b>", "</b>"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
bool isbold = false; // Start in normal mode
foreach (var part in parts)
{
     if (isbold)
        myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(part)));
     else
        myTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(part));

     isbold = !isbold; // toggle between bold and not bold
}
```

Comment: No, I dont want to use WebBrowser Control. And neither I want to display HTML. The text between `<b> and </b>` is an example. It can be the text between two stars instead of `<b> and </b>` or it can be anything. I just want to use that text as the text of the textblock.

Comment: And you can have any number of bold parts in your text?

Comment: Owww I didn't notice your update. Thank you. Found it more helpful than the 3rd answer.

Comment: @MichalHainc: guess why I asked for the number... It will probably become slow with thousands. Maybe it even gives OutOfMemoryException in a 32 bit process. But I do not like to optimize it for speed or memory until I know what the requirement is.

Answer (score 6):

It looks like you want to replace your custom formatting with `<Bold>` - see [TextBlock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more info. Sample from the article:

```
<TextBlock Name="textBlock1" TextWrapping="Wrap">
  <Bold>TextBlock</Bold> is designed to be <Italic>lightweight</Italic>,
  and is geared specifically at integrating <Italic>small</Italic> portions
  of flow content into a UI.
</TextBlock>
```

One approach is to re-format string to match what `TextBlock` expects.

If you have HTML input - parse the text with HtmlAgilityPack first and than walk though resulting elements and construct string with `b`-elements replaced with text wrapped `<Bold>` and similar to other formatting.

If database content is known to have only valid begin/end pairs (not random HTML) you may even get away with basic `String.Replace` : text = text.Replace( "", "")`.

If you have you own custom formatting (like `*boldtext*`) you'll need to invent custom parser for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can subscribe to `TargetUpdated` event:

```
 void textBlock_TargetUpdated(object sender, DataTransferEventArgs e)
 {
        string text = textBlock.Text;

        if (text.Contains("<b>"))
        {
            textBlock.Text = "";
            int startIndex = text.IndexOf("<b>");
            int endIndex = text.IndexOf("</b>");
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Substring(0, startIndex)));
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Bold(new Run(text.Substring(startIndex + 3, endIndex - (startIndex + 3)))));
            textBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run(text.Substring(endIndex + 4)));
        }
    }
```

and XAML for the `TextBlock`:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="textBlock" Text="{Binding NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"></TextBlock>
```

Comment: That's a very specific solution and works only in case 1 <b></b> is present